# Web API call giving "InvalidAuthorizationHeader"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to connect to an OData API using Advanced REST Client.

The Login is successful and I receive a SecurityToken which I use in the following GET request:

```
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
authorization: Basic <security-token>
```

Even though I am using the security token I received from the Login, I am receiving a message that says "The HTTP authorization header is not formatted correctly." and I also receive an "Authorization required" prompt in Advanced REST Client (ARC).

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the Authorization header or how I can format it correctly?

Comment: Try `Authorization: Bearer xxxxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with your token.
please show your login result.
In addition, My be It is because of authorization type that you use 'basic'.
Use 'Bearer'  with authorization  token:
authorization: Bearer ....